# Scala - runtime String template

Tags: java, string, scala

I want to do exactly what java's String Template does, but in scala. This library however does not work with case classes:

```
case class Obj(str:String)
val st = new ST("xx $obj.str$ xx",'$','$')
st.add("obj",Obj("replacement"))
st.render()  //returns "xx  xx"
```

ST tries to find property "str" with reflection, but it just does not work with scala.

How can I achieve it without ST?

Comment: What does "String Template" do?

Answer (score 0):

Try to create your class like this:

```
    case class Obj(@BeanProperty str: String)
```

Here is the scala doc: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.beans.BeanProperty

Also you can take a look at the project Scalasti which is a interface for StringTemplate: http://software.clapper.org/scalasti/

Answer (score -1):

It's built into the language (in an extendable way). Just

```
val obj = Obj("replacement")
s"xx ${obj.str} xx"
```

You can have any Scala expression inside `${...}`.

See http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/string-interpolation.html (or just search for "Scala string interpolation") for more.